# SwiftyJSON: Can't read array value from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I can't get my array of string from my JSON using SwiftyJSON. I have json like this

```
{
    "categories": {
        "202": "Women's Clothing",
        "104": "Men's Clothing"
    },
    "products": [{
        "price": 528500.0,
        "title": "Some title with long name",
        "id": "13864671"
    }..., ..., ...],
    "keywords": ["hoodie", "hoodie paramore i", "hoodie daft punk", "hoodie muse", "hoodie nirvana"]
}
```

My problem is, I can print categories and products but I cant print keywords. It just give me blank array `[]`. So what's wrong here?

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
    response in
    if response.result.error == nil {
        let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(json)
        success(json)
    }else{
        error("\(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

When I print `json`, my `categories` and `products` are fine except `keywords` that give me no value `[]`.

Here is my log on Xcode

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "111" : "Men's Clothing",
    "122" : "Women's Clothing"
  },
  "keywords" : [

  ],
  "products" : [
    {
      "price" : 123,
      "title" : "Long name product",
      "id" : "123123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try print the `response.result.value` itself and see if it also empty or not, probably your response is empty -_- not the SwiftyJSON fault

Comment: `response.result.value` give me the exact same thing with my  `print(json)`. Don't know where it goes wrong :(

Comment: then its your response is like that, try make request with something like Postman and see again

Comment: I use postman and I got `keyword` as an array of string. But if I fetch using alamofire, then it can't be read and give me empty array `[]`

Comment: Maybe your request have wrong params, try print the request out and check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

> Product.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class Product {

var price: Double?
var title: String?
var id: String?


init (json: JSON) {

    if let price = json["price"].double {
        self.price = price
    }

    if let title = json["title"].string {
        self.title = title
    }

    if let id = json["id"].string {
        self.id = id
    }
}

var description: String {
    get {
        var _description = ""

        if let price = self.price {
            _description += "price: \(price)\n"
        }

        if let title = self.title {
            _description += "title: \(title)\n"
        }

        if let id = self.id {
            _description += "id: \(id)\n"
        }

        return _description
    }
}
}
```

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var keywords = [String]()
var categories = [String:String]()
var products = [Product]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            //NSLog("\(json)")

            if let keywords = json["keywords"].array {
                for keyword in keywords {
                    if let keyword = keyword.string {
                        self.keywords.append(keyword)
                    }
                }
            }

            if let categories = json["categories"].dictionary {
                for key in categories.keys {
                    if let category = categories[key]?.stringValue {
                        self.categories.updateValue(category, forKey: key)
                    }
                }
            }

            if let products = json["products"].array {
                for product in products {
                    self.products.append(Product(json: product))
                }
            }

        }
    }

    print("keywords: \(keywords)")
    print("categories: \(categories)")
    print("products:\n")
    for product in products {
        print(product.description)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

> data.json

```
{
"categories": {
    "202": "Women's Clothing",
    "104": "Men's Clothing"
},
"products": [{
             "price": 528500.0,
             "title": "Some title with long name",
             "id": "13864671"
             },
             {
             "price": 528531200.0,
             "title": "!!Some title with long name",
             "id": "13223864671"
             }],
"keywords": ["hoodie", "hoodie paramore i", "hoodie daft punk", "hoodie muse", "hoodie nirvana"]
}
```

**result**

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?